# Module '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'StreamableFile'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

The import for StreamableFile doesn't seem to work, i tried updating nestjs but it didn't changed, im running the 7.6.15

`Module '"@nestjs/common"' has no exported member 'StreamableFile'.`

I've tried Updating nestjs and installing globally

Answer (score 1):

`StreamableFile` was added in `@nestjs/common` version 8. It doesn't exist back in v7

Comment: Is there a alternative in nestjs 7?

Comment: Using the old `stream.pipe(res)`. `StreamableFile` is mostly just a wrapper around that anyways

Comment: @MuriloAAAlves you could look at the source code of `StreamableFile` and implement it your side. Isn't hard